# Usage of “как” in the sense of “в качестве”

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление

> Она использует плед в качестве занавеса.
>   Она использует плед как занавеса.

1. Is this example correct and does *как* require the genitive here?
2. Are these two expressions interchangable?
3. Is there another common way to express the same?

Comment: You need "Она использует плед как занавес" without -а at the end of "занавес".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The second sentence is wrong, **как** doesn't require the genitive, it never requires any specific case. In the construction `Х как Y`, the Y noun phrase should be *in the same case* as the X noun phrase, and the case of X is defined by what precedes it, that is by the usual case rules of the sentence/phrase it is used in.

   In your first sentence the word **плед** is in the accusative since it is the direct object of the verb **использует**, so **занавес** should also be in the accusative:

   > Она использует плед как занавес.
2. Yes.
3. Yes, you can use **вместо** 'instead':

   > Она использует плед вместо занавеса.

   Here **занавеса** is in the genitive, because the preposition **вместо** always needs the genitive.

Comment: *In the construction `Х как Y`, the Y noun phrase should be in the same case as the X noun phrase* - that's a key hint to me. *вместо* does work here, but it seems to me, that it only covers a portion of the entire intersection between *как* and *в качестве*.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word `занавеска` is more natural here than `занавес`.

When I hear word `занавес` I imagine the curtain in the theater that is dropped at the end of performance.
When I hear `занавеска` I imagine the thing that is used to hide something from other eyes.

So, if we are really talking about the theater then the form `занавес` is correct. In other cases I would use the word `занавеска`.

Anyway, both versions sound good for me:

> Она использует плед в качестве занавески - OK
>
> Она использует плед как занавеску - OK, too

Comment: Ah, I didn't even think about that. Good point, too. Even if the heart of the question has been answered by yellowsky already.